# Elementwise multiplication of a matrix by a vector

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication, elementwise-operations

Suppose I have a matrix A=rand(2,14,24) and a vector x=10*ones(1,14)

I want element wise multiplication of A and x, such that B(i,j,k)=A(i,j,k)*x(j) for all j=1,2,..14. 
I want to be able to do this without running a loop. What is the most efficient way to do this in matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first use `repmat` to tile `x` the right number of times, then do element-wise multiplication.

```
repX = repmat(x, [size(A, 1), 1, size(A, 3)]);
B = A.*repX;
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're multiplying `A` by a vector of 10's element-wise, wouldn't it be easier to simply multiply by a *scalar* instead?

```
B = A * 10;
```

For a general case, there is no need for `repmat` logic here. `bsxfun` can do the trick (and it's faster). :

```
B = bsxfun(@times, A, x);
```

Comment: I need a general solution. I read the bsxfun page at MathWorks, but I am not able to understand how do I specify the right indices are multiplied?

Comment: @skr This _is_ a general solution, and you don't need to specify anything. `bsxfun` automatically replicates the smaller matrix (in our case `x`) along all non-singelton dimensions of the larger matrix (in our case `A`). So if `x` is a row vector, it will _automatically_ be replicated along the first and the third dimension.